# Can't install Perf4J Integration Plugin on Grails 2.5.1

Tags: grails, monitoring, grails-2.5, perf4j

I'm trying to install [Perf4J Integration Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/perf4j) for Grails.

I've added `compile ":perf4j:0.1.1"` on my BuildConfig.groovy but when I try to refresh my dependencies I get:

```
Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/me/Programs/test/target/work/plugins/perf4j-0.1.1/./Perf4jGrailsPlugin.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.perf4j.log4j.Log4JStopWatch
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.perf4j.log4j.Log4JStopWatch
   ^
/home/me/Programs/test/target/work/plugins/perf4j-0.1.1/./Perf4jGrailsPlugin.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.support.GrailsPluginUtils
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.support.GrailsPluginUtils
   ^
 2 errors
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
 ...
```

The second error is happens because [GrailsPluginUtils](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginUtils.html) has changed package from `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.support` to `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins`. I've found a fixed version on the a [Github fork](https://github.com/mglont/grails-perf4j-plugin).

But even when I try to compile the plugin sources downloaded from the Github repository linked above, I still get the `org.perf4j.log4j.Log4JStopWatch`.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Try this: compile "org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16"

Comment: @AntonHlinisty Just added it as a dependency on the plugin version I downloaded from Github and it worked. Looks like the perf4j dependency was missing. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I was able to install, but now I get an exception when I try to load a page. I'll play with it a bit and provide more information on my question soon.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your grails application still caches the old version of `perf4j`. You mentioned about the repository in github where we had cloned, fixed the missing packages and bumped the version to `0.2.1`.

In my experience, we did some works:

- clone, then either install it into the local maven repository or deploy to your owned company maven centre. For us, we deploy [per4j](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/%7Emaven/m2repo/org/grails/plugins/perf4j/) to EBI maven repository.
- If you would go with our deployment of `per4j`, you need to add `compile ":perf4j:0.2.1"` inside `plugins` section and add `mavenRepo "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~maven/m2repo"` under `repositories` section of `BuildConfig.groovy` located in `grails-app` directory.

How this would help you sort the issue out.